# How can I get Eclipse to auto-indent code blocks within if and for statements?

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

I tried to get Eclipse to convert all of the tabs in my project to spaces like this:

Java Editor:

- Click Window » Preferences
- Expand Java » Code Style
- Click Formatter
- Click the Edit button
- Click the Indentation tab
- Under General Settings, set Tab policy to: Spaces only
- Click OK ad nauseum to apply the changes.

And now my code is formatted without any indentations within if and for blocks, like this:

```
private void addAppointment(Resource resource) {
    if (resource != null) {
    Appt appt1 = new Appt();
    appt1.setTime(new Date());
    resource.setAppointment(appt1);
    }
}
```

I really don't want to have to manually fix this in the hundreds of files in the project, how can I format to indent within if and for blocks in the whole project?

I should also say that the "Statements within blocks" checkbox in the active Formatter profile is checked.  The preview it shows has a for block with an indented body, so I have no idea why that isn't being applied to my project.

Comment: Do you only want to convert tabs to spaces inside of if blocks?

Comment: No, I want to convert all of the tabs in the project to spaces.

Comment: a "must have" plug-in for Eclipse is [AnyEdit](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/) it adds lots of small but critical features to Eclipse, including a tab to space converter. It can operate on whole projects or individual files.

Comment: If you can't solve this, with the help of the answers, you'd need to supply the version of eclipse/myeclipse that you're using, and the OS, both of which might have a bearing on this. You should also check the error log for any relevant issues.

Answer (score 1):

@gnac provides some good options, in addition to:

> Similarly you can use ctrl+shift+f (Source->Format) on each class to format it on the fly

You can select the project(s) and do *Source* menu -> *Format* to format everything in that project in one go. (No keyboard shortcut for it AFAIK.)

Comment: I looked for that capability. Format was greyed out in the menu, but now I see it in the context menu, nice one.

Answer (score 0):

So once you set your formatting options you have a couple of options. You can set the preferences to format your files when saving.

```
Preferences->Java->Editor->Save Actions
```

However, if you have a lot of files this will be a pain as well. Similarly you can use ctrl+shift+f (Source->Format) on each class to format it on the fly, again having to do it on each file individually.

Inside Eclipse you can use Search->Find, enter "\t" in the text box and select the "Regular Expression" check box and then click the "Replace..." button. When the search is done, it will ask you what to replace it with. Enter 4 spaces into the "With" text field. Click Preview to see what it will do, or OK to make the changes.

I would use a find and sed to find all of the java files in a directory and replace the tabs, although this is outside of eclipse

```
find -iname ".java" -exec sed -i.orig 's/\t/    /g' {} +
```

If you're not on Linux you could use cygwin to do the same on Windows.

Comment: Just discovered expand instead of sed for this: find . -name '*.java' ! -type d -exec bash -c 'expand -t 4 "$0" > /tmp/e && mv /tmp/e "$0"' {} \;